# Using Oracle to query the first value of each week and so on

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table

> 2010-4-16  199
>
> 2010-4-19  310
>
> 2010-4-20  229
>
> 2010-4-21  275
>
> 2010-4-22  64
>
> 2010-4-23  504
>
> 2010-4-26  631
>
> 2010-4-27  565
>
> 2010-4-28  286

and the desiring result is :

> 2010-16   199
>
> 2010-17   310

...

I want to query the first value of weekly grouping data, and query is listed below:

```
 select distinct(to_char(date1,'yyyy-mm-w')) b,
first_value(a) OVER 
(partition by  distinct(to_char (date1,'yyyy-mm-w'))
 order by date1
range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )  c,

from t4
```

What is the correct solution about this question? I can query data, but not the actual result I want.
The result of sql query  which referred before result is

> 2010-16   199
>
> 2010-17   504

but unfortunately is not I want.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

By using your query little modified ::

```
 select distinct to_char(dt,'yyyy-iw') b,
first_value(num) OVER 
(partition by to_char (dt,'yyyy-iw')
 order by dt range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )  c
from tbl
order by 1;
```

you get o/p like this::

```
B   C
2010-04-15  199
2010-04-16  310
2010-04-17  631
```

you wanted to group the data based on the total week no for that date.

Please see i have used the option **'iw'** to get this results.

Comment: Is this your required query?